# How to perform pagination in the YouTube API?

Tags: python, java, pagination, youtube-api

I'm trying to perform pagination on the YouTube API, but I can't get more than 12 pages.

I am making the following request:
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=podcast&type=playlist&key={key}&relevanceLanguage=pt-BR&maxResults=50&regionCode=BR&snippet.categoryId=92`

From this request, I obtain the nextPageToken and make a next request, just adding the pageToken parameter to the query.
The problem is that when I reach the twelfth request, the nextPageToken field is no longer returned, and so I can no longer obtain the next pages.

I'm performing a for loop in Java to add the pageToken to each request. Until the twelfth, everything happens correctly, but from then on, what I mentioned above happens.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Check your API usage dashboard to see if you're hitting any quota limits....Review the YouTube API documentation to see if there are any specific limitations or restrictions mentioned for search queries.

Comment: I quite well documented [the YouTube Data API v3 Search: list endpoint 500 results limit](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/4) you are facing. TLDR: there is no workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm using an alternative to change the query every 500 results, this way I can get what I want.
For example, in the first iteration I use 'q=podcast', in the second 'q=podcasts'...